# Get Analyse Form API returned an error 3003

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I used the labelling tool to train my model, got the model ID, used the model ID to analyse the document and when called the Get analyse API received the error message as displayed on the screenshot. Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the labeling tool to predict the same document?

Comment: Yes. But, I now tried with the empty form (without handwritten information) and got the same error message.